# Is it possible to use typedef in a templated function signature?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef

Is there a way to use a typedef as an argument of a template function ? Or a way to define a type as an argument ?

let's say I want to pass a function pointer to this function :

```cpp
template<typename C, typename ...Args>
void test(typedef void (C::*functor)(Args... args) functor f)
{
   f(args...);
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: I know it's confusing, but a pointer to a member function is neither a function pointer nor a pointer. (Interesting related read: https://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=oldnewthing&y=2004&m=02&d=09&WeblogPostID=70002&GroupKeys=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't make a `typedef` in a parameter. If your goal is to avoid repeating the type of the parameter in the function body, you can use `decltype`:

```
template<typename C, typename ...Args>
void test(void (C::*f)(Args...))
{
   typedef decltype(f) functor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

But why would you even want that when you can write this:

```
template<typename C, typename ...Args>
void test(void (C::*f)(Args...), Args... args)
{
   C c;   //f is a member function, so need an instance of class
   (c.*f)(args...);  //call the function using the instance.
}
```

Or, you can pass the instance along with arguments, or  do something else. I assume it  is just a proof-of-concept, and in the real code would be something else.